# No updates for 14.10

Tags: apt, do-release-upgrade, lsb-release

When I look at

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=utopic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.10"
```

But my `/etc/apt/sources.list` is already all `vivid` (15.04).

Running `do-release-upgrade` does start the process but says there are 0 packages to be upgraded.

How do I fully update my system to vivid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at

```
apt-cache policy base-files
```

there I found out, that I **pinned** something.

I had a file

```
/etc/apt/preferences.d/vivid-manual-only
```

which sticks the vivid upgrade to manal upgrade only:

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=vivid
Pin-Priority: 99
```

Remove that file and your updates are found by

```
do-release-upgrade
```